# BIOS password needed - but none set by me

Tags: laptop, bios

> This computer system. #8NJBM1J-595B, is protected by a password authentication system. You cannot access the data on this computer without the correct password.

This message appear when computer was started. I can't open BIOS also. I have no password for this computer.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What model of Dell computer?

Answer (score 2):

If you are the owner, call Dell and ask for the master password for your system. If they give it to you, enter it when the BIOS asks for the password, then hold down the Control key and press the Enter key (that is, press Ctrl-Enter and not simply Enter). This will erase the password.